# springtoolsuite rest service not referencing function

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-tool-suite

I am new to java and trying to implement a rest web service with spring tool suite. I successfully ran an example from a guide and tried to add a POST function to the basic Hello World service. The web service is running using the Spring boot App and all I can trace is that the function is not found. 404 status. Here is code:

```
public class GreetingController {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestController.class);


@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name, HttpServletResponse httpResponse_p, 
                                        WebRequest request_p) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name));
}

// @Secured({ "ROLE_USER" })
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value= {"/addNewPage/{customername}/{streamname}/{name}"})
public Greeting addName(@RequestBody String body, @PathVariable("customername") String customername, @PathVariable("streamname") String streamname, 
                        @PathVariable("name") String name, HttpServletResponse httpResponse_p, WebRequest request_p) {

    if (customername.isEmpty() || streamname.isEmpty()) {
        String eMessage = "ERROR - NO PARAMETERS INCLUDED!";
        httpResponse_p.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        return new Greeting (counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template,  "BAD PARAMETERS"));
    }


    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format("WORKING - ADDED " + name));

}
```

So if I paste the following in my browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Al
```

I get the following correct response:

```
{"id":2,"content":"Hello, Al!"}
```

But if I try

```
http://localhost:8080/addNewPage/something/stream1/ABC
```

I get the following:

```
  Whitelabel Error Page

 This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing 
 this as a fallback.

 Tue Mar 24 17:19:29 EDT 2015
 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
 No message available
```

could someone see what I am missing here? Or be so kind to suggest a good step by step tutorial that goes through the following functions GET/POST/PUT/DELETE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paste the url in the browser you are doing a GET. Your mapping is for POST so a 404 error is what expected.

Normally when you POSTing you should have some data in the request body but anyway just for testing you can use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to send post requests.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-test-a-rest-api-from-command-line-with-curl/) on how to use it for testing rest apis